# creating an engine object for Google maps engine in java

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-engine

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/tutorial-create-map), but I'm having problems with creating the engine object (as described by the Java section of the code). I have 3 import lines that cant be resolved and I cant find where to get the files. i am still a novice coder so this is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/mapsengine/v1) for the java library and how you can import it

[Direct download link for a .zip file](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/mapsengine/v1/java)

For maven add to pom.xml:

```
<project>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-mapsengine</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev64-1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

for gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-mapsengine:v1-rev64-1.20.0'
}
```

---

By the way, Google Maps Engine API will stop working after jan 29th, 2016, so don't waste too much time getting used to it ;-)